# Probability of hitting two vectors

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, enumerative-combinatorics

Call an element of $ \{-m,\dots,0,\dots,m\}^{2^n}$ a *vector*.  Assume $m = O(2^{2^n})$.

Let $u_1,u_2$ be vectors.

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_{2^n}\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_{2^n}\}$ be linearly independent collections of vectors.

Let $c\geq1$.

Now let $\{i_1,\dots,i_{n^c}\}$ be a random sample of $n^c$ elements of $\{1,\dots,2^n\}$, selected uniformly.

What is the probability that there are some 
$r_1,\dots,r_{n^c}\in\Bbb R$ such that both
 $$u_1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n^c}r_{j}v_{i_j}\text{ and } u_2= \sum_{j=1}^{n^c}r_{j}w_{i_j}?$$

Under what conditions on $u_1,u_2$ and $\{v_i,w_j\}_{i,j=1}^{2^n}$ will this probability be bounded away from $0$ asymptotically?

Also what if $r_1,\dots,r_{n^c}\in\Bbb Q$?